# How to shorten a code to make multiple lists?

Tags: python, list

I'm making 12 lists that undergo the same process. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to make them all do this in a loop, and I've been forced to repeat the same code 12 times and take up a giant chunk of text.

Here's a small portion of the code I've had to write.

```
  l1 = []
  l1.append(random.choice(easy))
  if "none" in l1:
    l1.remove("none")
  else:
    psblnsrs.append(l1[0])
    easy.remove(l1[0])
  l1.append(random.choice(special))
  if "none" in l1:
    l1.remove("none")
  elif len(l1) >1:
    usblhks.append(l1[1])
  else:
    usblhks.append(l1[0])
  while sum(len(l1) for l1 in l1) < 12:
    l1.append(random.choice(junk))
  random.shuffle(l1)
  l2 = []
  l2.append(random.choice(easy))
  if "none" in l2:
    l2.remove("none")
  else:
    psblnsrs.append(l2[0])
    easy.remove(l2[0])
  l2.append(random.choice(special))
  if "none" in l2:
    l2.remove("none")
  elif len(l2) >1:
    usblhks.append(l2[1])
  else:
    usblhks.append(l2[0])
  while sum(len(l2) for l2 in l2) < 12:
    l2.append(random.choice(junk))
  random.shuffle(l2)
```

Keep in mind, there are *twelve* lists that need to be made, this is only *two*.

I'm not too familiar with coding massive loops and naming variables properly. I want something like this:

```
for i in range(12):
  l(i) = []
  l(i).append ...
```

Is there a way to make this work or a similar way to make this work?

Also, if the code is hard to understand, the source material is [here](https://repl.it/@BeardedPC/recreation).

Comment: You probably shouldn't have twelve variables called `l1, l2, ..., l12`. That's asking for unnecessary hassle. You could replace them all with a list with 12 elements in it. But call it something meaningful, not just `l`.

Comment: I would look into incorporating those first 17 lines or so into a function, then you can create a list of variables, as in `selections = [l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,...l12]`, then you can call your function `for lst in selections:`

Comment: @khelwood I'm having all 12 lists print their content on their own line. That'd require me to make one MASSIVE list and split it into 12ths

Comment: @G.Anderson that could work, could you give an example?

Comment: @BeardedPancake It would not require that. You can have a list with 12 elements where each element its own list. It doesn't involved splitting a list into twelfths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could probably do it pretty much just like your are doing it.

```
    lists = []
    for list in lists:
        list = []
        list.append(random.choice(easy))
        if "none" in list:
            list.remove("none")
        else:
            psblnsrs.append(list[0])
            easy.remove(list[0])
        list.append(random.choice(special))
        if "none" in list:
            list.remove("none")
        elif len(list) >1:
            usblhks.append(list[1])
        else:
            usblhks.append(list[0])
        while sum(len(list) for list in list) < 12:
            list.append(random.choice(junk))
        random.shuffle(list)
```

Unless I'm missing something about how your code works upstream, you should just be able to do that, you will end up with a list of lists, which you can reference by their index.  (e.g. lists(2))

Comment: hmm...this seems to work, but how would I recall a list in a list for printing? would it be `lists[<sublist>][<item in sublist>]` or would it be `lists[<sublist>[<item in sublist>]]`

Comment: lists[<sublist>][<item_in_sublist>] would be the correct syntax to access an item in a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Functions might come in handy

```
def make_list(inp_list1=psblnsrs, inp_list2=usblhks, easy_list=easy, special_list=special, junk_list=junk):
    l1 = []
    l1.append(random.choice(easy_list))
    if "none" in l1:
      l1.remove("none")
    else:
      psblnsrs.append(l1[0])
      easy.remove(l1[0])
    l1.append(random.choice(special_list))
    if "none" in l1:
      l1.remove("none")
    elif len(l1) >1:
      usblhks.append(l1[1])
    else:
      usblhks.append(l1[0])
    while sum(len(l1) for l1 in l1) < 12:
      l1.append(random.choice(junk_list))
    return random.shuffule(l1)

l = []
for i in range(12):
  l.append(make_list())
```

Comment: The lists themselves don't require input to be created, the two variables `psblnsrs` and `usblhks` mean "possible answers" and "usable hacks" and are items in the list.
I want the code use to make list `l1` and use a loop to make 12 more lists using the same process

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code

```
#Create a list to contain lists
myLists = []

#Add to our list 12 empty lists
for i in range(12):
    myLists.append([])

#Loop over each list and add 12 to each list.
for currentList in myLists:
    currentList.append(12)

#Print out the results
print(myLists)
```

by using `for currentList in myLists`, we can iterate over each list in our "list of lists" and perform operations on the currentList before moving on to the next one. Your code that therefore perform the same operations on each list in turn.

Comment: You're onto something, but how would I incorporate the code I've written for the current lists?

Comment: @BeardedPancake I'm afraid I don't understand what your code is intended to do so i can't provide a complete example. Perhaps if you explain what the 12 lists need to contain, I might be able to help. Would help if you had provided a complete executable example.

Comment: @BeardedPancake Generally speaking you should just be able to replace instances of `l1`, `l2` etc with `currentList`.

Comment: what would I replace `l1` with in the program I wrote to get the 12 different lists I need to make?

Comment: Replace `l1` with `currentList`. Once it is in a for loop currentList will on each iteration be the next list

Answer (score 0):

As khelwood pointed out, a better data structure for your twelve lists is to just store them in another list. That way you can access them with `super_list[0], super_list[1]`, and more importantly you can iterate over them with `for sublist in super_list: ...` rather than having to refer to them explicitly at all.

That way, you only have to write your logic once. What you're looking to do is define a function:

```
def list_update(current_list):
   '''
   List management logic code here.
   '''
   ...
   return current_list
```

Then in the main logic of your code:

```
for sub_list in super_list:
    sub_list = list_update(sub_list)
```

This way, when you have to make a change to the way you're handling those lists, you don't have to write the change 12 times, you only have to write it once.